# Java Socket Not Work

Tags: java, sockets

Socket.java: (User write anytext after click button i want to show on server.java)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GuiSocket extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    JButton    gonder;
    JTextField yazi, gelen;
    JPanel     panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 3));
    Socket     soket;
    DataInputStream   in;
    DataOutputStream  out;
    Thread th;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Throwable {
        GuiSocket gS = new GuiSocket();
    }

    public GuiSocket() throws IOException, Throwable {
        this.setTitle("Socket - kibAr");
        this.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(120f, 100f, 50f));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 413, 253);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(getRootPane());
        this.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        hazirla();
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }

    void ekranOrtala(){
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(getRootPane());
    }

    void  hazirla(){
        yazi   = new JTextField(50);    panel.add(yazi,   BorderLayout.WEST);
        gonder = new JButton("Gönder"); panel.add(gonder, BorderLayout.EAST);
        gelen  = new JTextField(3);     panel.add(gelen,  BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.pack();
        ekranOrtala();
            gonder.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",   Font.BOLD, 10));
            gonder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        out = new DataOutputStream(soket.getOutputStream());
                        out.write(yazi.getText().getBytes());
                        yazi.setText("");
                        out.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            yazi.setFont  (new Font("Consolas", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
            gelen.setFont (new Font("Consolas", 10, 10));

            gelen.setEditable(false);
            gelen.setToolTipText("Sunucudan Gelen Mesaj");
            gelen.setForeground(Color.RED);

            yazi.setHorizontalAlignment((int) JTextField.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            yazi.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            gonder.setToolTipText("Sunucuya Mesaj Gönder");

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            soket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3131);
            in = new DataInputStream(soket.getInputStream());
            while(in.read() != -1){
                gelen.setText(in.readUTF());
                if(in.readUTF().charAt(0) == 'Ç'){
                    gelen.setText("Çıkış yapılıyor..");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GuiServer  extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    JButton    gonder;
    JTextField yazi, gelen;
    JPanel     panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 3));
    Socket     soket;
    DataInputStream   in;
    DataOutputStream  out;
    Thread th;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, Throwable {
        GuiServer gS = new GuiServer();
    }

    public GuiServer() throws IOException, Throwable{
        this.setTitle("Server - kibAr");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 413, 253);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(getRootPane());
        this.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        hazirla();
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }


    void ekranOrtala(){
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(getRootPane());
    }

    void  hazirla(){
        yazi   = new JTextField(50);    panel.add(yazi,   BorderLayout.WEST);
        gonder = new JButton("Gönder"); panel.add(gonder, BorderLayout.EAST);
        gelen  = new JTextField(3);     panel.add(gelen,  BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.pack();
        ekranOrtala();
            gonder.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",   Font.BOLD, 10));
            gonder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        out = new DataOutputStream(soket.getOutputStream());
                        out.write(yazi.getText().getBytes());
                        yazi.setText("");
                        out.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            yazi.setFont  (new Font("Consolas", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
            gelen.setFont (new Font("Consolas", 10, 10));

            gelen.setEditable(false);
            gelen.setToolTipText("Sunucudan Gelen Mesaj");
            gelen.setForeground(Color.RED);

            yazi.setHorizontalAlignment((int) JTextField.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            yazi.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            gonder.setToolTipText("Sunucuya Mesaj Gönder");

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket sS;
        try {
            sS = new ServerSocket(3131);
            soket = sS.accept();

            --- Delete after work. > soket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3131);
            in = new DataInputStream(soket.getInputStream());
            while(in.read() != -1){
                gelen.setText(in.readUTF());
                if(in.readUTF().charAt(0) == 'Ç'){
                    gelen.setText("Çıkış yapılıyor..");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When I run server after run socket, I write input any text after clicking 'gonder' button, but cannot see the text I wrote on the server's window.

What is the problem?

Comment: The code looks great. One tip: always use accessors for variables. This helps to avoid threading bugs, eases debugging and logging, allows subclasses to override default behaviour (the Open-Closed principle), subscribes to the DRY principle (avoids reading/writing instance variables in multiple locations), guards against NullPointerExceptions, and allows for lazy initialization.

Comment: i cant resolve this problem :/ so i work hard but ...

Comment: okey i solve problem,